# CSS for two column jQuery UI Sortable List grid that handles elements of different sizes

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to get a drag-and-drop two-column sortable list going. I've got it set up jQuery UI's SortableList with a single `<ul>` and `<li>`'s that are `float:left` and half the width of the `<ul>`

Here's the code and example: http://jsfiddle.net/elidickinson/hjnkg/

Basically I want to eliminate the gap between item3 and item5 in that jsfiddle link. I want to be able to drag any of those elements around and not leave any internal gaps.

I don't see any obvious way to solve this in CSS, so my best idea is to write some JS that looks for any "tall" items that appear in the right-hand column and switches them to `float:right`. That should solve the problem, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.

I'm also open to any alternative approache like using two separate columns with no floats. That solves the problem for "tall items" but I think it would take some CSS magic to deal with "wide" items that take up two columns.

Comment: Also, if there's an easy way to get that placeholder to be the same size as the thing that's being dragged, that would be nice.

Comment: Might want to read this about handling your floats: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388697/why-do-some-floated-elements-decide-to-clear-both. Might want to look into http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html as well.

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing plugins out there allow for draggable sorting.  The closest thing I can find is http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html, which does have a sortable by button option.  This is a REALLY complex problem that I don't think anyone has undertaken yet, at least not publically.  Here is  a post from the creator of Isotope: http://metafizzy.co/blog/mythical-drag-drop-multi-column-grid-plugin/

Buuttttt, if you want to get the placeholder the same size, do something like this:

```
$('#list').sortable({ 
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        tolerance:'pointer',
        start: function (event, block) { 
            // set the placeholder size to the block size
            $('.ui-state-highlight').css({
                'width':$(block.helper).outerWidth(),
                'height':$(block.helper).outerHeight()
            });             
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for that, looks very slick and that blog post is pretty on point. Masonry basically does exactly what I want, so it's unfortunate that no one has a nice generic solution to tying it to Sortable or Draggable. However... I think I can hack up a solution that works for my narrow case of just two columns and three box sizes, unless I'm missing something. I'll post an update either way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very hacked together version of the javascript solution I suggested in my question. It seems to work, but it sure ain't pretty. Here it is in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/elidickinson/tRjDM/

```
function update_columns() {
    var column = 1;
    var orient_1past = '';
    var orient_2past = '';
    $("#dashboard-layout .item").each(function() {
        var $item = $(this);
        var orient_current = 'normal';
        if ($item.hasClass('wide')) {
            orient_current = 'wide';
        }
        if ($item.hasClass('tall')) {
            orient_current = 'tall';
        }

        if ((orient_2past == 'tall') || (orient_1past == 'wide') || orient_1past == '') {
            // do nothing
        }
        else {
            // move to next column
            column = (column == 1) ? 2 : 1;
        }

        // remove any existing columns classes
        $item.removeClass('column1').removeClass('column2');

        // add class for calculated column
        $item.addClass('column' + column)

        // keep track of previous two item orientations                
        orient_2past = orient_1past;
        orient_1past = orient_current;
    });
}
```

Plus some CSS rules like:

```
.item.column1 { float: left; }
.item.column2 { float: right; }
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing that.  If only someone would be brave enough to try a solution for N columns now.  :)

Comment: It should be possible with absolute positioning, it nothing else. Really, it seems like Masonry already did a lot of the hard parts, but I'm not that brave.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer Isotope, but again, that doesn't allow sorting.  I tried to take a crack at something, but with very little luck.  It's a tough problem...

Answer (score 0):

We had success resolving a similar (but not identical) issue using the `change` option of the the `sortable` function. Our problem was that we had some "tall" LI elements in the two column list, and when those tall elements were in the first column, other items would pile up in the second column adjacent to the tall elements since all the LI elements were `float: left`. This would make for very strange interaction when sorting.

To get around the issue, you can apply `clear: both` to all the LI elements in the first column (all the odd elements), however things get screwy in the middle of a sort because there is an extra LI element in the list with absolute positioning (the one being dragged), and it throws off the even and odd selectors.

The solution was to use the `change` callback that is invoked every time the DOM changes during sorting. You can then use jquery to accurately figure out which are the LI elements that are actually in the first column and apply `clear: both` to those elements.

```
     function setClearsOnFirstColumn() {
        var colNum = 0;
        $(".myList").find( "li:not(.ui-sortable-helper)" ).each( function() {
            var thisLiEl = $(this);

            if( colNum == 0 )
                thisLiEl.css( "clear", "both" );
            else
                thisLiEl.css( "clear", "none" );

            colNum ++;
            if( colNum == 2 ) colNum = 0;
        } );
    }

    $(".myList").sortable( { change: setClearsOnFirstColumn, stop: setClearsOnFirstColumn } );
```

The `not` part of the selector serves to ignore the LI element being dragged (identified by its `.ui-sortable-helper` class) when determining which are the LI elements in the first column. (Could also shorten this by using even and odd jquery selectors - it is not done that way here only because the snippet was adapted from a more general case to support more than two columns in the list.)

Note you also need to call `setClearsOnFirstColumn` after the list is initially rendered.)